# If then else in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am an old dog struggling with R as a new trick

I want to replicate the follow SAS code in R (using a dataframe with multiple columns):-

```
if sum5 > 0 then gbind = 1;
else if  sum4 > 0 then gbind = 2;
else if block19 in ('B') then gbind = 3; (many other elements)
else gbind = 0;
```

Please Help

Comment: Did you try anything? Where exactly are you getting stuck? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825/code-translation-tagging

Comment: If (newblocks201802a$sum5 > 0) {gbind1 < - 1
} else {
If (newblocks201802$sum4 > 0) {gbind1 < - 2
}  else gbind < - 0
}      got unexpected } messages

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to use `ifelse`. Without knowing the strcuture of your data this is the best I could come up with:

```
gbind <- ifelse(sum5 > 5, 1,
          ifelse(sum4 > 0 , 2,
          ifelse(block19 == 'B', 3,0)))
```

See this link for more details: [ifelse](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/ifelse)

Comment: Thanks(Mike), I will try it out, very appreciated